# Keep my 3d player from jumping if he's not on the Ground

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, 3d

I'm making a 3d game, and I have only made games in 2D before, but i have used blender before too.  My player can now walk and jump, but he is not limited to only jumping of the ground.  In 2D, you separated ground objects in a collision layer, and in the jump method you add an if statement like this

```
if(myCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("climbing")))
{
    //do the stuff
}
```

Apparently this is designed for 2d only.

How do I do this in 3d?

Comment: Did you search for [existing Q&A on ground checks](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+ground+check) / [grounded state in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+grounded) or [existing guides and tutorials to follow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ground+check+unity)? This is something that's been covered hundreds of times before. What did you try based on your research, and where specifically did you run into trouble?

Comment: I checked the Q&A and found an answer.  it was in the question, "How to stop jumping again when character is in air (double jump)?"  I had looked before, but hadn't found anything.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! I'm marking this question as a duplicate of the one you mentioned for the time being. If you find that the solution you gleaned from that Q&A isn't serving your needs, edit this question to describe what you tried and how it's deviating from what you need, and we can re-open it for new answers.